# How do I identify if my EarPods lightning are original?

Tags: iphone

When I connect the EarPods purchased along with iPhone from suspect source I see this:

[image]
[image]

Is this not weird? Are they original or not?

Comment: Earpods (with a cable) or AirPods (without)?

Comment: with a cable... Please, look that they are Earpods, not Earphones;) iPhone shows they are earphones, but I connect earpods.

Comment: EarPods (https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMTN2AM/A/earpods-with-lightning-connector) usually don't trigger any connection dialog at all, they just show up as "Headset" when you select the output device. So by connecting you mean you plug them in and the dialog from the screenshot is displayed?

Comment: Yes, by connecting I mean plug them in and the above dialog is displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshots you have are identical to ones I have seen before with third party (non-original) minijack-to-Lightning adapters.

The EarPods that comes with an iPhone matches the iPhone. Therefore if you have an iPhone with just a Lightning connector, then your EarPods should have had a Lightning plug and not require an adapter.

This seems to indicate that the EarPods you have did not originally come with that iPhone. Whether they are are original or not is hard to say from the information given - it might be original EarPods with a non-original minijack to Lightning converter.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that the word Beats at the top of the 2nd image is misspelled I'd think it would be safe to say that the Earpods are not original.

Comment: Actually the original should now show Beats at all... this particular combination of Beats and Baets is what makes me think it is one of these non-original adapters that I wrote about in my answer. This is how they typically look - they're actually Bluetoothey devices.